# Update value of javascript variable used in jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I am new to Nodejs + Express Jade, I am using a javascript variable in index.jade

```
-var a = 10
h1= a
```

Its displaying 10 in jade page, but what if value of 'a' changed after some execution, it will still be displaying 10, i want to display new value of variable 'a', any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to communicate the change to front. I recommend node for create an API and then use angular or react to query it. You can even use a simple socket.io application to interact with your view.